# How can I assign a unique value to represent a list of unique integers

Tags: hash, integer, set

I need to compare two lists of unique integers by assigning each list a unique value to represent it's integers. What method/algorithm can I apply for this that's not too computationally intensive and produces a relatively short id/hash a set

Both lists:

- have a unique set of integers ranging from 1 to 1000
- are ordered

For example:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4...55,57...999]
l2 = [1,2,3,4...54,56...999]
```

l1 is missing 56 while l2 is missing 55.
All I need to know in this case is that the lists are not identical so I can update l2.

Comment: range of  the integers in set? hash conflicts happens, theoretically worse , when you ask for short hash on large ranged integers .  Any code you tried ?

Comment: In general, what you're asking for is not possible. But if you give us more information, such as how large your lists are and the range of integers in those sets, it's possible that we can come up with a solution for you.

Comment: @JimMischel Each list will have unique integers ranging from 1 to 1000. Thanks

Comment: *How many* integers in the list? Up to 1000?

Comment: Also, does order matter in the list? Is `[1,2,3,4]` considered different from `[4,2,3,1]`? And how many lists do you expect to have? How long is a "relatively short" id? A 32-bit number? 64-bit number? An alphanumeric sequence of some fixed length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated after comment**

See below for an explanation of why you can't use a hash code to assign "each list a unique value to represent its integers."

However, a hash code *can* be useful. Assuming you create a hash code for each list. You'll want to make sure that you sort items in the lists before computing the hash code, because order definitely matters in hash code computations. That won't necessarily generate a unique hash code for each list, but if the hash codes for two lists aren't identical, the lists are definitely different. If the hash codes are identical, the lists *might be* identical. The code, then looks like this:

```
bool AreListsIdentical(list1, list2)
{
    if (list1.hashCode != list2.hashCode)
    {
        // hash codes are different, so lists are definitely not identical
        return false;
    }
    // hash codes are equal. Lists might be identical.
    if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
    {
        // lists have different numbers of items. Definitely not identical.
        return false;
    }
    // have to compare individual items
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (list1[x] != list2[x])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

**Previous answer**

You have multiple lists, each of which contains unique numbers in the range 1 to 1,000. You don't say how large each list is, but for illustration purposes I'll say that each list contains 10 numbers.

You also don't say whether order matters in the list. Is the list `[1,7,99,206]` the same as `[99,7,206,1]`? I'll show you the calculations either way.

The number of permutations (order matters) of 1,000 items taken 10 at a time is 9.56E+29. The number of combinations (order doesn't matter) is 2.63E+23. Those are huge numbers.

You say you want a "relatively short id." We can express a 64-bit value easily in a 12-character string, so let's assume that you want to create a 64-bit hash code. There are 1.84E+18 possible 64-bit values.

There are one hundred trillion times more possible permutations than possible hash codes. There are 100,000 times more combinations than hash codes.

Applying the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you have *n* things that you want to put in *m* boxes. Since *n > m*, at least one box will contain more than one item. *You can't possibly have a unique 64-bit value for each list.*

(In truth, assuming a good hash function, every hash code will represent approximately the same number of different lists.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've revised my question to include more information